# how to get values on change event in dynamic angular forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-reactive-forms, eventemitter

On component.ts file I am fetching the form field values in json array like this and converting it to an FormGroup control like this.  This is working perfectly fine.

```
    getJsonForm(){
      let base_url = 'example.org'
      let getform_query = '/Base/formfieldsgenerator_get';
      let getform_endpoint = base_url.concat(getform_query);

     this.AllFormData = [];

        this.http.get('getform_endpoint'.'?tabpgrpid='+this.tabpgrpid+'&tabgrpname='+this.tabgrpname+'&usertabgrpname='+this.usertabgrpname+'&moduleid='+this.moduleid+'&templateid='+this.templateid+'&all_mod_data='+this.all_mod_data,{headers: this.headers}).subscribe(
        res => { 
         this.AllFormData = res;

                // this array is used to iterate in html side
               this.newfdata[element] = [];
               this.newfdata[element]['properties'] = [];


   Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).forEach(inputKey => {
                      this.newfdata[element]['properties'].push(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][inputKey]);

                });

            // this is used to create form controls and form groups

                this.objectProps = Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties']).map(prop => { 

          return Object.assign({}, { key: prop} , res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop]);
          });

   for(let prop of Object.keys(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'])) {

          formGroup[prop] = new FormControl(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop].value || '', this.mapValidators(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop].validation));

                }
        });

      this.form = new FormGroup(formGroup);
          }); 
}
```

Now on components.html side I am using the array like this to generate the dynamic form. This is also working fine.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="custom_submit(form.value)" [formGroup]="form" >
         <div *ngFor="let input1 of newfdata[tabname].properties">   
                <ng-container *ngIf="input1.type=='string'">
                                <div>
                                     <mat-form-field>
                                     <input matInput  [formControlName]="input1.field_name" [id]="input1.field_name" type="text"  placeholder="{{input1.title}}">
                                     </mat-form-field>   
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
         </div>  
</form>
```

Now I want to change the value of one form field based on changes on previous form fields. For that I am not able to subscribe to the valuechanges emitter of the form group variable.

I have tried this on ngOnit but it's not working and not producing any result in console.

```
ngOnit(){

   this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
                    this.formattedMessage = 'My changed values for is ${val}.';
                    console.log(this.formattedMessage);
                  });



}
```

Edit 1 :

After suggestion from Manzur Khan, I have passed the valueas true for the success of formcreated event and then in ngOnit used the value like this to get the onchange event :

```
      this.form = new FormGroup(formGroup);
      this.dataService.change_current_form_created("true");
```

and in NgonIt

```
this.dataService.last_form_craeted_message.subscribe(data => {
  if(data=="true") {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
         this.formattedMessage = 'My changed values for is ${val}.';
            console.log(this.formattedMessage);
        });
}
});
```

Now I am able to log on change event in console but not able to get the resolution for ${val}.

Edit 2 :

Since the val is object, I was not able to resolve ${val} somehow,I Simply did

```
   this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            console.log('the changed value is',val);
        });
```

It gives me all the values of given formgroups. I still need to optimize this result further so that I just listened to specific form controls. But it has give me a road to go. Thanks all.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your query. Its to confusing whats your actual query is due to extra stuff.

Comment: Not put the code in ngOnInit, just AFTER your line: this.form = new FormGroup(formGroup). Well, for clarity, create a function and call it after the line

Comment: "Now I want to change the value of one form field based on changes on previous form fields". Well, think if the value must belong to the form or not.e.g. if your "field" formattedMessage is "My ChangeValue"+input1.value, you can not have this "field", just a < span>{{"My change Value "+form.getControl('input1').value}}< /span>

Comment: @mayur : This is the actule code snippt to make you understand the whole scenario. Nothing here is extra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening because you are listening to value changes of the form even before the form is present(since it's inside async)

You can try something like this

First declare an Observable

```
formCreated: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
```

Then in your form code

```
this.form = new FormGroup(formGroup);
this.formCreated.next(true)
```

and then in your ngOnInit

```
this.formCreated.subscribe(data => {
  if(data) {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
         this.formattedMessage = 'My changed values for is ${val}.';
            console.log(this.formattedMessage);
        });
}
})
```

Comment: When I do this . it gives me two errors, ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at AddComponent.ngOnInit  and Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber , So should I need to defined this.formCreated somewhere? IF so, how?

Comment: @Manzur Khan, You needn't create a formCreated submited. just, after create the form (is a sync function), create the subscription to valueChanges

Comment: @Eliseo , I am checking with your approach.

Comment: @Manzur Khan, I created one common shared service which holds the value as true after form is created like this.

     this.form = new FormGroup(formGroup);
    this.dataService.change_current_form_created("true");

where this.dataService is commong service I am using to pass the messages to diff. components. 

Now I am able to log the value change event in the console but Getting only message like this, My changed values for is ${val}.'; and not the value itself.

Comment: @Manzur Khan, Please orovide correct defination or declaration of Formcreated, (In my case I created an behaviour, observable subject). So that I can mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Eliseo , I tried your suggestion and it also worked fine. earlier I did the same but I was doing out side of http.call and hence as Manzur said, it was going out of the sync.

Comment: @Jaydeep Glad you found it helpful, I've updated the answer as per your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
formGroup[prop] = new FormControl(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop].value || '', this.mapValidators(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop].validation));
```

Try to add controls to the form, it worked for me. You can do that by using form.addControl:

```
formGroup.addControl(prop, new FormControl(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop].value || '', this.mapValidators(res['com'][element]['schema']['properties'][prop].validation));
```

Answer (score 0):

I still need to optimize this result further so that so that I just listened to specific form controls?? , I have some different solution for you which may work for your requirements.

**template.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="custom_submit(form.value)" [formGroup]="form" >
 <div *ngFor="let input1 of newfdata[tabname].properties">   
  <ng-container *ngIf="input1.type=='string'">
   <div>
    <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event,input1.field_name)"[formControlName]="input1.field_name" [id]="input1.field_name" type="text"  placeholder="{{input1.title}}">
    </mat-form-field>   
   </div>
  </ng-container>
 </div>  
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
 public modelChanged(ev, formName) {
   console.log('Jarvis Event', ev);
   console.log('control value', this.form.get(formName).value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use *form control* object to create an event on a particular dynamic form HTML element.
**e.g.**

```
this.form.controls["DynamicFormControlId"].valueChanges.subscribe(val => {

    });
```